# How to merge two json objects coming from a file

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

I have two json objects coming from a file. Those two objects make one record. They are of different length. I was using pandas.read_json(), but didnt work.
Here is an example:

input:

```
{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3}{"x":[100],"y":"123"}
```

expected output:

```
{
   "a":1,
   "b":2,
   "c":3,
   "x":[100],
   "y":"123"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

IIUC, You want to read two JSON and create a new JSON from them.

```
import json

new_json = {}
for json_file in ['js1.json', 'js2.json']:
    with open(json_file) as f:
        d = json.load(f)
        new_json.update(d)
        
print(new_json)
# {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'x': [100], 'y': '123'}

# create a new json that contains two old json
res = json.dumps(new_json)
```

**Update** You can use [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval), If two JSON in one file.

```
import json
import ast

# jss.json -> {"a":1,"b":2,"c":3}{"x":[100],"y":"123"}

new_json = {}
for json_file in ['jss.json']:
    with open(json_file) as f:
        jsons = f.read()
        for js in jsons.split('}')[:-1]:
            st = js+'}'
            d = ast.literal_eval(st)
            new_json.update(d)
        
print(new_json)
# {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'x': [100], 'y': '123'}

# create a new json that contains two old json
res = json.dumps(new_json)
```

Comment: thanks. I have those two json objects in a file. there is no any delimiter between them to split to get into a list

Comment: @Sridhar, see update